# A reference for a combinatorial identity involving a product of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, summation, binomial-coefficients

The following combinatorial identity is (12.12) in H. W. Gould's [https://web.archive.org/web/20171118022119/http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.4.PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20171118022119/http://www.math.wvu.edu/%7Egould/Vol.4.PDF): Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. Then

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n+\alpha}{n-k}\binom{k+\alpha+1}{k}=\begin{cases}
1 & n=0\\
-1 & n=1\\0&n\geq 2.
\end{cases}$$

Do you know of additional references? Please do not provide a proof, only references.

Comment: Cannot open your reference link. How about we give you some hints instead of full answer?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Weird. It works for me. Try this link: https://web.archive.org/web/20190629193344/http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/
Please no hints.

Comment: @Sela: This is a well-known identity in disguise. So, a reference request to *this* representation might not be that relevant and therefore not that easily found, since most other citations will use a more prominent representation.